# suming two dataframes pandas python

Tags: python, dataframe

I have two dataframes

```
         colA    colB   amount1    amount2     key  
maindf = xx      yy     12         1           55_ab
         qs      rr     13         2           14_rs

        colA    colB   amount1     amount2     key           
df =    dd      tt     10          5           55_ab
```

I want to add the values of field amount1 and amount 2 of dataframe df to maindf based on field key to get the following

```
         colA    colB   amount1    amount2     key  
maindf = xx      yy     22         6           55_ab
         qs      rr     13         2           14_rs
```

Answer (score 0):

what about using pandas - merge df and than create new column/columns as described below (just sum two columns)
join - left = maindf, right = df, how = 'left', left_on='key', right_on = 'key'

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'$a':[1,2], '$b': [10,20]}) # creating fake df
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'$a':[1,2], '$b': [10,20]}

dfMerge = pd.merge(left=df, right=df2, how='left', left_on='$a', right_on='$a')
dfMerge["SUM"] = dfMergeTemp["$b_x"] + dfMergeTemp["$b_y"]

# print(dfMergeTemp)
```

in your case (maybe it would make sense to rename your columns not to be confused what is happening)

```
mergedDf = pd.merge(left = maindf, right = df, how = 'left', left_on='key', right_on = 'key')
```

Comment: I don't want an extra column.

Comment: Is there anyway that values from second dataframe add up to the values of maindataframe directly ?

Comment: You can drop any additional columns or just select columns of your interest. so the results would be as you want to but still quite simple to do.

Answer (score 0):

What about this?

```
# make main df
main = pd.DataFrame({'ColA' : ['xx', 'qs'],
                     'ColB' : ['yy', 'rr'],
                     'amount1' : [12, 13],
                     'amount2' : [1, 2],
                     'key' : ['55_ab', '14_rs']})

# make other df
df = pd.DataFrame({'ColA' : ['dd'],
                   'ColB' : ['tt'],
                   'amount1' : [10],
                   'amount2' : [5],
                   'key' : ['55_ab']})

# merge dataframes
df1 = main.merge(df,
                 how = 'left',
                 left_on = 'key',
                 right_on = 'key').fillna(0)

# sum amount1
df1.insert(df1.shape[1],
           'amount1',
           df1.amount1_x + df1.amount1_y)

# sum amount2
df1.insert(df1.shape[1],
           'amount2',
           df1.amount2_x + df1.amount2_y)

# drop unneeded columns
df1.drop(['amount1_x',
          'amount2_x',
          'ColA_y',
          'ColB_y',
          'amount1_y',
          'amount2_y'],
         axis = 1,
         inplace = True)
```

[image: df]

Comment: Is there more simple as in fact my dataframe looks more like

Comment: it is much bigger with 20 columns and some fields have composed names as 'pnb 2016'

Comment: Please provide an example of your actual dataframe then (dimensions and all). Can't provide you an answer if you don't provide proper example data.

Answer (score 0):

```
Pôle        Libellé entité          PNB N-1         PNB N initial       Key
IBFS        PJSC ROSBANK            -200            0                   zz_t55
IBFS        PJSC ROSBANK            0               1500                bb_y44  
IBFS        PJSC ROSBANK            1000            2000                az_89   
IBFS        PJSC ROSBANK            5000            -250                rr_14
```

So this is the maindf
Lets say there is much more columns and I cannot post everything.
So I want sum up values from another data frame which have the same key to the fields 'PNB N-1' and 'PNB N initial'